# Suppose $\{X_n, n > 1\}$ are independent non-negative random variables satis­fying $E(X_n)= \mu_n \> Var(X_n)=\sigma^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

Suppose $\{X_n, n > 1\}$ are independent non-negative random variables satis­fying
$$E(X_n)= \mu_n \> Var(X_n)=\sigma_n^2$$
Define for $n \geq 1$, $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ and suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n = \infty$ and $\sigma_{n}^2 \leq c \mu_n$ for some $c > 0$ and all $n$. Show $\frac{S_n} {E(S_n)}\rightarrow^{P} 1$.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Hint: Note that $\text{Var}[S_n] \le c\mathbb{E}[S_n]$, and recall [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement).

Comment: Don't you need to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\frac{S_n}{E(S_n)}-1| \geq \epsilon)=0$ @stochasticboy321

Comment: Posted an answer. I found using Markov's inequality on $(S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n])^2$ to be more intuitive, as you don't have to manipulate things to fit into Chebychev's.

Comment: Stop putting on hold interesting questions....

Answer (score 2):

I'm using markov's inequality below - $P(X \ge a) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}$

\begin{align}\mathbb{P}\left\{ \left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} - 1\right| \ge \epsilon\right\} &= \mathbb{P}\left\{ \left|{S_n} - {\mathbb{E}[S_n]}\right| \ge {\mathbb{E}[S_n]}\epsilon\right\}\\ 
&= \mathbb{P}\left\{ \left|{S_n} - {\mathbb{E}[S_n]}\right|^2 \ge (\mathbb{E}[S_n]\epsilon)^2\right\}\\
& \le \frac{\text{Var}[S_n]}{\epsilon^2 (\mathbb{E}[S_n])^{2}}\\ 
&\le \frac{c}{\epsilon^2 (\mathbb{E}[S_n])} \underset{n \uparrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\end{align}
Since $\mathbb{E}[S_n] = \sum \mu_n \to \infty$